# How do i access request.user in self.client.post Testing

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Quote which has a ForeignKey pointing to User.
I want to make a post request to create a Quote but i don't know what data i should give to self.client.post, this is what i got so far i am talking about the test_can_save_a_POST_request:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase

from quotes.models import Quote
from quotes.views import home_page

User = get_user_model()

class HomePageTest(TestCase):

def test_uses_home_template(self):
    response = self.client.get('/')
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')

def test_display_all_quotes(self):
    user1 = User.objects.create(email="rafik@test.com", password="foo")
    Quote.objects.create(text='quote 1', user=user1)
    Quote.objects.create(text='quote 2', user=user1)

    response = self.client.get('/')

    self.assertIn('quote 1', response.content.decode())
    self.assertIn('quote 2', response.content.decode())

def test_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
    user1 = User.objects.create(email="rafik@test.com", password="foo")
    self.client.post('/', data={
            'quote_text': 'The first ever quote'
        }
    )
```

Comment: Use `self.client.force_login(user1)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login

Comment: But how do i assign that user to the post request?

Comment: After the client is logged in the user will automatically be sent with every request

Comment: How can i put you're comment as the correct answer it now works good !!!